# ¿Como puedo hacer que al momento de ingresar un elemento a una arreglo en java este primero verifique si se encuentra?

Tags: java

//Aqui tengo la entrada pero como podria hacer que lo verifique;

```
Clase []c=new Clase[10];
int i=0;
do{
   System.out.println("Ingrese numero de cuenta");
   c[i]=entrada.readLine();
}while(i<c.length);
```

i+;

Answer (score 1):

Hay una manera fácil con los utils de java.

```
Clase []c=new Clase[10];
int i=0;
do{
   System.out.println("Ingrese numero de cuenta");
   String line = entrada.readLine(); 
   if(java.util.Arrays.asList(c).indexOf(line) == -1) {  
     System.out.println("El número de cuenta ya existe");
   } else {
     c[i] = line;
   }
}while(i<c.length);
```

asList es un metodo estático que convierte un array en una lista temporalmente para poder aprovechar todas las ventajas que ofrecen las listas de Java.

IndexOf obtiene el indice donde se encuentra ese elemento, si no existe, regresa -1

Más información 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

Podria implementar un ciclo for para busqueda despues de la entrada del dato y antes de ingresarlo al arreglo.

```
Clase []c=new Clase[10];
int i=0;
do{
  System.out.println("Ingrese numero de cuenta");
  int value = entrada.readLine();

  for(int ii=0; ii < c.length(); ii++)
  { 
    if(value != c[ii])
    {
     c[i]= value;
    }
  }
i++:
}while(i<c.length);
```

Espero te ayude.
Saludos.